# Extract a known length substring starting from known substring

Tags: string, bash, shell, text

I am trying to parse a text file with a known format, however each line is not 100% consistent.

Each line of the file contains some data in the format ...x03: 0xDEADBEEF...x04: 0xDEADBEEF...x05: 0xDEADBEEF...ect

I want to be able to extract particular x values from this string and print them to stdout.

I cannot figure out the best way to do this string search, I am sure there is a solution using sed that I haven't figured out, hopefully someone can help.

I have tried a very simple pamaeter expansion using offsets, but found the string wasnt formatted exactly the same on every line.

I have now tried this:

`for line in data.txt; do grep -Po 'x10:[^.]*' $line; grep -Po 'x05:[^.]*' $line; grep -Po 'x06:[^.]*' $line;grep -Po 'x07:[^.]*' $line; done`

this seems to print all of the x10 followed by all of x05 ect.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried a very simple pamaeter expansion using offsets, but found the string wasnt formatted exactly the same on every line.

I have now tried this:

`for line in data.txt; do grep -Po 'x10:[^.]*' $line; grep -Po 'x05:[^.]*' $line; grep -Po 'x06:[^.]*' $line;grep -Po 'x07:[^.]*' $line; done`

this seems to print all of the x10 followed by all of x05 ect.

Comment: @user3552845, Good, that you have let us know your efforts, request you to add them in your question with CODE TAGS and let us know then, comments are not meant for adding samples.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my problem.

```
let count=1
while read line; do
    echo "Test Result: ${count}"
    let count=count+1
    grep -Po 'x10:[^.]*' <<< "$line"
    grep -Po 'x05:[^.]*' <<< "$line"
    grep -Po 'x06:[^.]*' <<< "$line"
    grep -Po 'x07:[^.]*' <<< "$line"
    grep -Po 'x22:[^.]*' <<< "$line"
    grep -Po 'x23:[^.]*' <<< "$line"
    grep -Po 'x24:[^.]*' <<< "$line"
    grep -Po 'x25:[^.]*' <<< "$line"        
    grep -Po 'x26:[^.]*' <<< "$line"
    grep -Po 'x27:[^.]*' <<< "$line"
    echo
done < data.txt
```